# Exception in use of OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

Following is code which i am running :

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Main_Extraction
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
    System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
}
}
```

this code is having no compile time error.
but, it's giving me run-time exception which is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -    Erroneous tree type: <any>
at Main_Extraction.main(Main_Extraction.java:9) Java Result: 1
```

please, suggest the solution to remove this exception.

Comment: this is just a test code, purpose is to check openCV working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution, add this paths in your environment variable CLASSPATH. this will work.

```
C:\javacv\javacv.jar;
C:\javacv\javacpp.jar;
C:\javacv\javacv-windows-x86.jar;
C:\javacv\jna.jar;C:\javacv;
c:\opencv2.4\build\x86\vc10\bin;
```

set this according to your javacv installed folder.

Comment: look, OP is *not* using javacv

Answer (score 0):

You have attempted run a program that has compilation error in it.  Fix the compilation errors BEFORE you try to run your program!!

---

> this code is having no compile time error.

That is not true.  The actual "compiled" bytecode file you are attempting to run is throwing an exception that says *clearly* that there was a compilation error of some kind.

Perhaps you are trying to compile a stale version ...

Perhaps you are compiling against a corrupted copy of the OpenCV JAR.

Perhaps you are using a buggy compiler ... and it crashed, giving you a bogus ".class" file.

Comment: give me your email i mail you pic of no compilation error in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the PATH variable is set correctly and opencv libraries are included, there is nothing wrong in the code.

Please follow this tutorial here for step by step installation of opencv in eclipse 
http://nenadbulatovic.blogspot.de/2013/07/configuring-opencv-245-eclipse-cdt-juno.html